# Too many DML statements: 1 in LWC, even when using imperative call

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, cacheable

I am creating a LWC that has a data table where you can check some boxes, and then a button that should update a particular field on those rows. Nothing crazy. But I am getting this error: **System.LimitException - Too Many DML Statements: 1.**

```
editStores()
{
    var selectedRecords = this.template.querySelector("lightning-datatable").getSelectedRows();  
    //console.log(selectedRecords);

    updateStores({stores: selectedRecords})  
    .then(result=>{  
      return refreshApex(this.stores);  
    })  
    .catch(error=>{  
        this.errorMsg = JSON.stringify(error);  
    })  

}
```

Then the Apex controller:

```
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=false)
    public static void updateStores(List<Customer_Notes_Accounts__c> stores) {
        for(Customer_Notes_Accounts__c s : stores)
        {
            s.Implementation_Date__c = Date.today();
        }
        
        update stores;
    }
```

I have done plenty of googling and every result says 1. I can't have cacheable as true since my method does DML (I removed it and even explicitly set it to false) and 2. I need to call it imperatively (I am). I am stumped on what else to do here. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried updating the records in bulk instead of updating them individually ?

Comment: Consider trying to do a hard refresh (and/or manually clear your cache). It's possible your browser is still caching something from before you made the change to `cacheable=false`.

Comment: Use debug and check what processes are running. Maybe the object Customer_Notes_Accounts__c has many processes in flows/triggers

Comment: Your code is still missing bulkification elements, such as adding each store where you need updates s.Implementation_Date__c = Date.today(); to a List and then update the list outside the FOR loop. Also, chacheble=false is correctly annotated. 
Even after these changes, if you encounter issues, check for any other DML operations being executed before or after this code.

Comment: Can you add your comment as an answer @AdrianLarson?

Answer (score 0):

Consider trying to do a hard refresh (and/or manually clear your cache). It's possible your browser is still caching something from before you made the change to `cacheable=false`.